# Statistical functionalities of F# (or .NET libraries)

Tags: f#, statistics

Is it possible for a person working with statistic to replace his specialized programs by F#?  I'm thinking about SAS/SPSS mainly?

Any native support for it in F#?

I am not talking about the trivial things as standard deviation and the likes, but for example  item-response modeling.

UPDATE : Dont't let the item-response modeling put you of! I don't even know it, just an example of things I know they do with SPSS to clarify it's about more advanced features.

Short : is there a way to use F# as your main statistical tool and replace SPSS all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, nothing comporable to combination of
R + PostgreSQL + Python/Java/Groovy/Scala/... + VisAD

Of course, there is nice http://www.codeplex.com/vslab instead of gnuplot
and some c# statistics code packaged in http://ta-lib.org/ http://www.alglib.net/

Answer (score 2):

You can use R within F# with the type providers for R

see

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2013/01/30/twelve-type-providers-in-pictures.aspx

and see

http://techblog.bluemountaincapital.com/2012/08/01/announcing-the-f-r-type-provider/

> Here at BlueMountain we like to perform statistical analysis of data.  The stats package R is great for doing that.  We also like to use the data retrieval and processing capabilities of F#. F#’s interactive environment lends itself pretty well to data exploration, and we can also easily access our existing .NET-based libraries.  Once we are done, we can build and release production-supportable applications.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something maybe-useful:

http://fsmathtools.codeplex.com/

or

http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/